# Protractor: assert video is playing

Tags: typescript, protractor, html5-video, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

In my web application built with Angular, I have a `<video>` element that I would like to test using [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org).

What I need to do is

1) **Play** and **pause** the video

2) Assert whether **the video is playing or not**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you share HTML before clicking the play button, after clicking the pause button and when the video is over?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , its possible. There is a HTML element `paused` which returns a boolean and tells if the video is paused or playing.

Below is the code I am using and it works like charm.

```
 async returnVideoState() {
    let pausedState = browser.executeScript(() => {
      return document.getElementsByClassName('videoelm').paused;
    });
    return pausedState;
  }


    async assertIfVideoIsPlaying(bool) {
    _isPaused = await this.returnVideoState();
    expect(_isPaused).toBe(bool);
  }
```

Usage:

```
   async pauseVideo() {
await this.pauseVideo();
await this.assertIfVideoIsPlaying(true);
  }
```

When video is Paused it should return true and false when being played.